# Authentication between REST and SOAP WebServices

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, saml, simple-web-token

We have a REST Web Service, it acts as a gateway for our SOAP Web Service. I realize that I could add one more endpoint to the existing web service, but I can't due to requirements.

Now I am dealing with the authentication process. So, I would like to use SWT authentication for the REST web service and SAML token authentication for SOAP Web Service.

So it seems that I have to implement following things:

1. Client uses a STS Server(Azure Access Control Service for simplicity) in order to obtain the SWT token.
2. Sends it to REST service as a part of request.
3. Rest Web Service converts it to SAML token
4. Rest Web Service calls the SOAP service.

Did I miss something, or would it work?